# Mostrar text area en front end

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy agregando textarea en un custom type de wordpress.
Tengo problemas para mostrarlo en el front end, intente de varias maneras..
Estoy cerca, pero no encuentro el error, alguna ayuda?

Esta es la plantilla:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

 ?>
<div class="single-property-element property-description">
    <div class="ere-heading-style2">
        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Precio', 'essential-real-estate' ); ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="ere-property-element">

   <?php
   function global_notice_before_post( $notice ) {

    global $post;

    // retrieve the global notice for the current post
    $global_notice = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sub_description', true ) );

    $notice = "<div class='sp_global_notice'>$global_notice</div>";

    return $notice ;

}



 ?>

    </div>
</div>
<?php  ?>
```

De esta manera agregue el campo de texto en el backend (se encuentra funcionando)

```
add_action("admin_init", "subdescription");
add_action('save_post', 'save_subdescription');
function subdescription(){
add_meta_box("sub_description", "Sub Description", "meta_function", "property");
}
function meta_function(){
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$sub_description = $custom["sub_description"][0];
wp_editor( $sub_description, 'subdescription', $settings =
array('textarea_name'=>'sub_description','dfw'=>true) );
}
function save_subdescription(){
global $post;
update_post_meta($post->ID, "sub_description", $_POST["sub_description"]);
}
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Faltaría al menos agregar `global_notice_before_post` con un `add_filter`, algo así:  `add_filter( 'the_content', 'global_notice_before_post' );`. [Revisa este tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-meta-boxes-post-types-wordpress/) donde se explica paso a paso lo que quieres hacer.